# leetcode 104. Maximum Depth of Binary Tree - Почему неверный результат в одном из тесткейсов?

Tags: javascript, дерево

При тестировании всё работает, но при попытке сабмита, на одном из тесткейсов выдаёт неверное значение. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в причине.

Input: `root = [null,3,-1,5,1,null,6,null,8]`

Output: `5`

Expected: `4`

Код:

```js
function maxDepth(root: TreeNode | null): number {
    if (!root)
        return 0;
        
    let q = [];
    let levels = 0;
    
    q.push(root)

    while (q.length) {

        for (let i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
            const node: TreeNode = q.shift();

            if (node.left)
                q.push(node.left)
            if (node.right)
                q.push(node.right)
        }
        ++levels;
    }
    return levels;
    
};
```

Comment: Задачу нам самим искать надо? Приведите условие и ссылку на задачу.

Comment: выглядит некорректным вводом `[null,3,-1,5,1,null,6,null,8]`

Comment: @MBo, в принципе номер указан _leetcode 104. Maximum Depth of Binary Tree_: https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-depth-of-binary-tree/

Comment: Похоже первый `null` лишний

Comment: очень плохая идея менять коллекцию, когда ты по ней бежишь в цикле со счетчиком. Фактически ты каждый второй узел пропускаешь сейчас, если не больше